# Android Emulator Screen keeps going up

Tags: java, android

I am using Android studio's emulator, when i have lots of data in one screen then emulator keeps on going to top of the page when i am editing my textViews, buttons etc.
Emulator 4 api 31

I tried looking for fixes in emulator but finds none.

Comment: can you please share video for the same

Comment: Remove and add again image... or AVD Manager -> "action" column -> run Cold Boot Now

Comment: Cold Booting also did not solve the problem, i think it's a bug.